# How to express multiple property set criteria for node selection using gremlin query

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, tinkerpop3

Here is my simplified graph schema,

```
package:
  property: 
   - name: str (indexed)
   - version: str (indexed)
```

I want to query the version using multiple set of property criteria within single query. I can use `within` for a list of single property, but how to do it for multiple properties?

Consider I have 10 `package` nodes, `(p1,v1, p2,v2, p3,v3,.. p10,v10)`

I want to select *only* nodes which has `(p1 with v1, p8 with v8, p10 with v10)`

Is there a way to do with single gremlin query?

Something equivalent to `SELECT * from package WHERE (name, version) in ((p1,v1),(p8,v8),(p10,v10))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always best to provide some sample data when asking questions about Gremlin. I assume that this is an approximation of what your model is:

```
g.addV('package').property('name','gremlin').property('version', '1.0').
  addV('package').property('name','gremlin').property('version', '2.0').
  addV('package').property('name','gremlin').property('version', '3.0').
  addV('package').property('name','blueprints').property('version', '1.0').
  addV('package').property('name','blueprints').property('version', '2.0').
  addV('package').property('name','rexster').property('version', '1.0').
  addV('package').property('name','rexster').property('version', '2.0').iterate()
```

I don't think that there is a way that you can compare pairs of inputs and expect an index hit. You therefore have to do what you normally do in graphs and choose the index to best narrow your results before you filter in memory. I would assume that in your case this would be the "name" property, therefore grab those first then filter the pairs:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('package','name', within('gremlin','blueprints')).
......1>   elementMap().
......2>   where(select('name','version').is(within([name:'gremlin',version:'2.0'], [name:'blueprints',version:'2.0'])))
==>[id:3,label:package,name:gremlin,version:2.0]
==>[id:12,label:package,name:blueprints,version:2.0]
```

Comment: This is perfect!. Thanks a lot @stephen mallette

Comment: This is not usable with binding. e.g. I want to query for 10 set of inputs.

Comment: no - it won't work with bindings. my answer is actually really strange given your question. i'm surprised i answered that way. it was almost like i answered a different question somehow. anyway, i've re-written my answer completely.

Comment: I thought of another hack, basically combining the two properties as a single one. In my specific use case, instead of having [name, version] separately, I could combine it as `name@version`. This would enable to use `within` directly.

Answer (score 1):

this might not be the most "creative" way of doing that,

but I think that the easiest way would be to use `or`:

```
g.V().or(
    hasLabel('v1').has('prop', 'p1'),
    hasLabel('v8').has('prop', 'p8'),
    hasLabel('v10').has('prop', 'p10')
  )
```

example: https://gremlify.com/6s

Comment: it is not working when I have plenty of nodes., it always times out. I do have indexing set for `name` and `version` properties.